# RESTEasy will not map my Spring bean with custom Spring ContextLoader

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resteasy

- RESTEasy 2.0.1GA
- Java 1.6
- Spring 3.0.3

I have tried everything I can, and cannot make head or tail of what's going on.  I have a Spring MVC application, however I'd like to have some RESTEasy endpoints available *outside* the Spring MVC app, but in the same container, ultimately being able to wire in the same beans.

As a first step, I'm simply trying to stand-up RESTEasy inside the container, serving requests from a Spring-configured bean.  I have tried the boilerplate from the instructions and have also tried manual setup, to no avail.

### Bean

```
@Resource
@Path("/")
public class NeighborComparison {

    private String foo;

    @GET @Path(value="customer") @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getNeighborComparison() {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

### `web.xml`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/api</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- NOT configuring SpringContextLoaderListener because I declare my own, so if I do, everything
     blows up, plus  all it actually does is sanity check configuration -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.MyCustomContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

### `applicationContext.xml`

```
<bean id="resteasy.providerFactory" class="org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory"
      factory-method="getInstance">
</bean>

<bean id="resteasy.dispatcher" class="org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher">
    <constructor-arg ref="resteasy.providerFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="resteasy.spring.bean.processor" class="org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringBeanProcessor">
    <description>
        Add Resources and @Providers to the appropriate places
        in Resteasy's infrastructure
    </description>
    <constructor-arg ref="resteasy.dispatcher"/>
</bean>

<bean id="neighborComparison" class="opower.api.customer.neighbor_comparison.NeighborComparison">
</bean>
```

According to the documentation, all I have to do is “manually register the RESTeasy BeanFactoryPostProcessor by allocating an instance of org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringBeanProcessor”.  I believe this spring configuration does that.

Jetty starts and the app context spins up with no issues.  Application works normally, however when I

```
> curl -H"Accept: text/plain" localhost:8080/ei/api/customer
```

("ei" is the application context).  The log shows (this and only this):

```
2011-03-29 16:44:24,153 DEBUG [qtp-575315405-0] [EI] [] [asy.core.SynchronousDispatcher] PathInfo: /customer
2011-03-29 16:44:24,156 DEBUG [qtp-575315405-0] [EI] [] [asy.core.SynchronousDispatcher] Failed executing GET /customer
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for relative : /customer of full path: http://localhost:8080/ei/api/customer
```

Even if I could convince RESTEasy to show me the mappings, it seems that it's just not discovering my bean.

If I map it explicitly via the `resteasy.resources` context param, it works, though obviously doesn't have access to auto-wired Spring beans.

Anything else I can try?  I have debug log on the entire RESTEasy codebase and I don't get any messages.  I've also confirmed that Spring is, in fact, creating my bean, so it's just that RESTEasy isn't finding it.

Comment: Spring MVC has its own REST-style framework. Why not just use that, and avoid this whole problem?

Comment: Spring MVC "rest" framework is incredibly weak and feature-starved compared to JAX-RS

Comment: If your code sample is an example of this, then it's easily capable of it.

Comment: Dave, can you please share correct solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your resource class needs to be annotated with `@Path` annotation for RESTeasy to pick up on it during bootstrap:

```
@Path("/customer")
@Resource
public class NeighborComparison {

    @GET @Path("/{customerId}") @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getNeighborComparison(@PathParam("customerId") long customerId) {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

Note the `@Path("/{customerId}}` annotation without which your `@PathParam` parameter would not have been mapped correctly, resulting in a pretty detailed exception (and an accompanying 500 response on the client side). Assuming the service is picked up by RESTeasy of course.

In addition if you don't use RESTeasy's `SpringContextLoader`, you have to make sure your `SpringBeanProcessor` instance is registered with the `ApplicationContext`. RESTeasy delegates to it by registering an `ApplicationListener` in `SpringContextLoader`:

```
  ApplicationListener listener = new ApplicationListener() {
     public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof ContextRefreshedEvent) {
           ContextRefreshedEvent cre = (ContextRefreshedEvent) event;
           ConfigurableListableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory = (ConfigurableListableBeanFactory) cre
                 .getApplicationContext().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
           new SpringBeanProcessor(dispatcher, registry, providerFactory)
                 .postProcessBeanFactory(autowireCapableBeanFactory);
        }
     }
  };
  configurableWebApplicationContext.addApplicationListener(listener);
```

If using a custom context loader and *not* the RESTEasy-provided one, this code has to appear somewhere in your context loader so that everything gets wired up.  A bit convoluted, yeah. It is `SpringBeanProcessor` that goes through all Spring beans and registers with RESTeasy those that have a `@Path` annotation somewhere in their hierarchy (type and their corresponding interfaces).

Comment: The code paste was old; I'm using @Path at the top and don't have that path param any longer.  Can you explain the context of the code you posted, tho?  do I need code like that somewhere in my app and, if so, where?  I am instantiating RESTEasy's SpringBeanProcessor in my app context…it doesn't seem to be doing anything

Comment: OK, nevermind, this code was helpful; I wasn't reading the codebase correctly, and forgot a bit of info in my question.